# Edit gave me double rep and shows double edit but second edit blank

Tags: bug, edits, suggested-edits

I was "rolling back" a post via changing it back to it's first revision, since I can't truly roll back posts yet. As I was doing this, I submitted my edit, and then after a few seconds noticed some grammatical and spelling errors in the post. I fixed those, and resubmitted the edit. The edit had not been accepted yet. After it was accepted, I got 4 reputation from the edit. The edit history is also wacko, like this:

[image]

When clicking on the suggested button on that revision, it directs me to my first edit's suggested edit page, the 3rd revision. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20448588/revisions) is the revision history of that post. This smells like a bug to me.

Comment: Interesting.. [link to revisions here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20448588/revisions) if anyone wants to see.

Comment: Is a bug, but nobody knows *why*.